# width:100% failed to make textarea as wide as parent element in IE6?

Tags: css, textarea, width

related snippet as follows:

```
<textarea class="w100"></textarea>

.w100 {
    width:100%;
}
```

It works in firefox but not in IE6,
why and how to fix this bug?

**EDIT:**AFTER ADDING A DIV,IT WORKS NOW.

```
<fieldset>
                                        <div>
                                            <textarea class="w100"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </fieldset>
```

Comment: Could you be more specific ? On the way you use those texte area, what really is the probleme? Do you have a screenshot so we can figure what your problem is all about ?

Comment: IE on the whole has problems with percentage based width sizing. For instance, to take the entire screen IE requires a width of 101%, versus FF's 100%.

Comment: What fo you mean specifically when you say that it "doesn't work"? What happens? The width is relative to the size of the parent element, so what have you put the textarea in?

Comment: Post your edit as answer and mark it accepted to avoid the Community poke this topic up again because it's unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing IE6 ?

Seriously have you checked all your margins and paddings ?

Answer (score 0):

IE6 does not handle %sizes very well in some cases (and this is obviously one of them). If you put th textarea inside a div tag that has width set to 300px, you might see that it is fit to 100% of the div tag, but it doesn't work (I think) if the width of the div tag is 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to make the body and html to be 100% as well.
I makes no sense (the body sould always be 100% of its own width, right?) but it seams to do the trick:

```
.html
{
  width:100%;
}
.body
{
 width:100%;
}
```

Comment: since the problem is that the textarea does not fill its container (as I understood, it goes for any container) the issue doesn't remain in the html and body styles. (well I guess anyway)